# parsing random strings using c++

Tags: c++, string

I have some strings that do not follow any specific pattern .. e.g

`t_pl_temperature +=`
`temperature =`
`t_temperature`
`temperatureArray[]`

`"     temperature_temp"` .. with spaces in the beginning

`#define temperature`
`temperatureTemp`
`int temperature;`
`current_t_temperature`

`temperatureHigh`  `lowtemperature`  `return(t_temperature)`

I want to change only **temperature** and so far I have used

```
std::string str = temperature;
size_t start_pos = str.find (str);
replace (start_pos, str.length(), "changed");
```

While doing this it changes every occurance of *temperature* with other text in the same line. I did some custom checking of characters that comes after and before *temperature* using the combination of *str.at(start_pos)* and *str.at(start_pos + str.length())* and some delimiters using

```
using namespace boost;
std::ostringstream s;
char_separator<char> sep("=");  
tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(str, sep);
for (const auto& t : tokens) {
    s << t;
}

return s.str();
```

Its working for some of the occurances of *temperature* and my question is, is there some library function or any other way that would return only **temperature** ? or do I have to do it manually until I die ?  :)

Actually its a huge code of thousands of lines and I need to parse it, thats why i need a generalized solution. Your suggestions/comments .. please !!

Thanks :)

Comment: This sounds like a job for http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: I don't see why you're using boost tokenizer... just need something like `(start_pos == 0 || !isidn(bigstr.at(start_pos-1)) && (start_pos + str.length() == bigstr.length() || !isidn(bigstr.at(start_pos + str.length())))`, where `isidn` checks for a valid character for an identifier, `bigstr` is your overall text, and `str` is temperature - you can't call them both `str`.  Regular expressions are another good option... I think it's `\b` that checks for word boundaries.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this with c++ and not a shell script?

Comment: @Tony D .. yeah I have already tried these combinations and they work but not every time. e.g it changes _temperature_ but what if the next string to be changed is *t_temperature* and so on .. I know regular expressions is an answer but I was kind of avoiding it, but seems like i have to get into the boat !

Comment: if the next string is `t_temperature` the test above won't match  because `!isidn(bigstr.at(start_pos-1))` will recognise the underscore as a legal character in identifiers... isn't that what you want?